# Failed at the electron-mksnapshot@1.6.0 install script

Tags: visual-studio-code

Downloaded vscode source . Following their instructions to build , when I ran

```
scripts\npm.bat install
```

Failed at the electron-mksnapshot@1.6.0 install script.

the console also shows the below:

```
 D:\vscode-master\node_modules\extract-zip\index.js:35
  zipfile.readEntry()
          ^

TypeError: zipfile.readEntry is not a function
at D:\vscode-master\node_modules\extract-zip\index.js:35:15
at D:\vscode-master\node_modules\yauzl\index.js:31:7
at D:\vscode-master\node_modules\yauzl\index.js:96:14
at D:\vscode-master\node_modules\yauzl\index.js:342:5
at D:\vscode-master\node_modules\fd-slicer\index.js:32:7
at FSReqWrap.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:629:17)
```

I have installed extract-zip v 1.6.5 , this is mentioned in dependency. No Idea what is going wrong here. I deleted the node_modules and build file and checked again. Does not seem to work. Can you somebody please guide me here ?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem today when I compiled the vscode source code with the npm@5.

You can try to remove the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` first. It solved this problem on my mac.

The reason seems zip path got undefined which should be `~/.electron-gyp/.electron/mksnapshot-v1.6.0-darwin-x64.zip`.

Comment: Where is `npm-shrinkwrap.json` located?

Answer (score 0):

Installed 4.6.1 . Didn't work initially. Took a fresh vscode source and built again and this seemed to do the trick. I had opened a git issue also and some people have posted their own solution to it.

Please check [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30775) git link issue.

Regards,